# postgres invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, pg-dump, pg-restore

my origin database is with SQL_ASCII encoding and my future database is with UTF8, wich is in another server.

well... I export with this command:

```
pg_dump -v -E UTF8 -Fc -h x.x.x.x old-database-name -U username > backup.dmp
```

and try import with this one

```
pg_restore --single-transaction -v -Fc -d new-database-name -U username <  backup.dmp
```

but i facing with this error:

> pg_restore: [arquivador (bd)] Erro ao PROCESSAR TOC: pg_restore:
>   [arquivador (bd)] Erro no registro do TOC 722; 1255 4594720 FUNCTION
>   Whatever(character varying) username pg_restore: [arquivador (bd)]
>   could not execute query: ERRO:  sequência de bytes é inválida para
>   codificação "UTF8": 0xe1 0x72 0x69

if i dumping and restore without -E parameter works well, but my new database is with characteres problems

Answer (score 1):

well... i had to dump like plain text and removed invalids characters with this command on linux:

```
iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 <backup.sql >backup-cleaned.sql
```